# Uniform convergence, indicator functions and Schwartz functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I'd like to know if following sequence converges uniformly:
$$f_n (x)=f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}(x)$$
Where $f\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ and $\chi_{[-n,n]}$ is indicator function of interval [-n,n].

Now we know that $f_n=f$ on interval [-n,n] and outside that interval $f(x)<C/x^2$ where C is specific for a given schwartz function. We can now put:
$$\epsilon=C/n^2$$
and therefore for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n$ so that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$. We have proven uniform convergence on $\mathbb R$.

In the book that I am reading they are using it in a proof but the indicator function is first convoluted with mollifier. They use the properties of the mollified function in other parts of the proof. I want to know if my proof is correct even though the sequence does not consist of continuous functions.

Comment: Yes, your proof is fine.

Comment: The proof is essentially correct, but badly phrased. When you say "We can now put $\epsilon=C/n^2$" it sounds as though you're _choosing_ $\epsilon$. You're not allowed to say what $\epsilon$ is, $\epsilon>0$ is given. The proof would be exactly right if you changed that sentence to this: "Now given $\epsilon>0$ we choose $N$ so $C/N^2<\epsilon$. If $n>N$ then $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for every $x$."

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. I guess I didn't do much exercise on uniform convergence. I was surprised that this could converge uniformly and didn't believe it. Thanks for the correction too. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments the proof is correct so indeed the product of Schwartz function and indicator function can converge uniformly to the Schwartz function.